# Extracting some values from a multi column text file

Tags: java

Lets say I have a text file like this:

```
ALASKA             30-DEC-11                                                  
CD  STATION         ICAO  IATA  SYNOP   LAT     LONG   ELEV   M  N  V  U  A  C

AK ADAK NAS PADK  ADK   70454  51 53N  176 39W    4   X     T          7 US

AK AKHIOK           PAKH  AKK 
         56 56N  154 11W   14   X                8 US

AK AMBLER           PAFM  AFM          67 06N  157 51W   88   X                7 US

AK ANAKTUVUK PASS   PAKP  AKP          68 08N  151 44W  642   X                7 US
```

I am only interested in saving lines that start with AK.  In addition, I need to save certain information into arrays, like my STATION name for instance.

For the first line I want to store "ADAK NAS" into a stationArray, "51" into an array, same with "53", "N", "176", "39" and "W".  I want to do this for each line that starts with AK.

I'm really quite confused on how to go about this.  My current code pertaining to this is as follows:

```
//process text file
FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("file.txt");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
String strLine;

//add lines that start with "AK" to arraylist
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null && strLine.startsWith("AK")) {
    list.add(strLine);
}

Iterator itr;
for (itr=list.iterator(); itr.hasNext(); ) {
    String str = itr.next().toString();
    String [] splitSt =str.split("\\t");
    String junk1 = "\\t";
```

I pulled the iterator part from online, and don't know how to split it there, or how do put the respective values into an array.  I'd appreciate any help that you can offer.  Thanks!

Comment: What is this weather report format called? It's apparently not METARS (which was the only thing I could find in google from the row headers). If you know the name of the format, look for a parsing library.

Comment: (You can iterate over an array of strings with `for(String s : list) { ... }` )

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is.  It looks like you've split each line into an array of strings.  What is it you want to do after that?

Comment: In reference to my earlier comment, does this library eat the format you have? http://sourceforge.net/projects/jweather/

Comment: Please don't use DataInputStream to read a text file. You don't need it so please remove it as people might copy this code.

Answer (score 0):

Is this sort of what you're looking for?

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String[]> out = new ArrayList<String[]>();
while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null && strLine.startsWith("AK"))
{
    list.add(strLine);
}
for(String line : list){
    String[] lineArr = str.split("\\t");

}
for (itr=list.iterator(); itr.hasNext(); )
{
    String delimiter = "\\t";
    String [] splitSt =str.split(delimiter);
    //we don't know how many we're going to find,
    //so we should accumulate the data in a List.
    out.add(splitSt);
}
String[] stationArray = out.toArray(new String[out.size()]);
```

Answer (score 0):

your code will exit the while loop @ the first line wich don't start with "AK"
 
you should replace
while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null && strLine.startsWith("AK"))
            {
            list.add(strLine);
            }
by

while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
            if(strLine.startsWith("AK"))
            list.add(strLine);
            }
by

Answer (score 0):

This looks more like a fixed width file (Fields in specific positions) or some varation on a fixed width file. In which case you can substr function to get the fields (note you should also test string length):

```
while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    if ( strLine.startsWith("AK") {
       field1 = strLine.substring(.., ..);
       field2 = strLine.substring(.., ..);
         ......
    }
}
```

If there are a lot of fields you could look at one of the **Flat file readers** packages that support fixed width files (i.e. [JRecord](http://jrecord.sourceforge.net/), [Flatworm](http://flatworm.sourceforge.net/) + many other's). In this case they may be an overkill

Here is a slightly changed version of the supplied file (if the original listing is accurate, some fields have embeded CR / New Line / Tab characters. The CR/New Line chars will make reading more difficult).

```
ALASKA             30-DEC-11                                                  
CD  STATION         ICAO  IATA  SYNOP   LAT     LONG   ELEV   M  N  V  U  A  C

AK ADAK NAS         PADK  ADK   70454  51 53N  176 39W    4   X     T          7 US

AK AKHIOK           PAKH  AKK          56 56N  154 11W   14   X                8 US

AK AMBLER           PAFM  AFM          67 06N  157 51W   88   X                7 US

AK ANAKTUVUK PASS   PAKP  AKP          68 08N  151 44W  642   X                7 US
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you sure you can't **fetch** this data from the source directly ? A database maybe ?
2. No other formats available ?

Else, I should say regular expressions should save you A LOT of hassle from parsing these lines. You can easily extract the fields you need without loops and conditional processing.

Yet a wise man once said, when someone attempts to solve a problem using regular expression, he now has 2 problems.